# Java: do while string issue

Tags: do-while

I have an issue when I run this program, If I use int it works, but for string it does not.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class userinput_swutch_do_while {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    

        String password= null;
        Scanner value = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            System.out.println("Enter the password for ATM: ");
            password = value.nextLine();
            System.out.println("You put : "+password);

        } while  (password !="55");


        System.out.println("You got it!");

    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

In JAVA, String equality is tested correctly using `equals()`or `equalsIgnoreCase()`;
That being said, you can try this :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class userinput_swutch_do_while {

public static void main(String[] args) {    

    String password= null;
    Scanner value = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
        System.out.println("Enter the password for ATM: ");
        password = value.nextLine();
        System.out.println("You put : "+password);

    } while(!(password.equals("55")));// string equality 


    System.out.println("You got it!");

  }

 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I tried with equals()or equalsIgnoreCase(); but my question is if anyhow we can use "==" or "!=" for this particular program?

Comment: If it answers your question then mark it as answered; by the way you're welcome

Comment: "==" and "!="  compare objects reference (roughly) whereas equals the actual content for quick answer